# Prove that Lorenz's Postulate is logically equivalent to Parallel Postulate 5

Tags: geometry

Lorenz, Every single line through a point within an angle will meet at least one side of the angle.

I know I have to Show that the parallel postulate 5 implies lorenz, and then lorenz implies parallel postulate 5.

Assume postulate 5 . So we are given AB and a point C not on AB. Choose B on AB draw CD to construct angle ECD= angle BDC.

I just don't get what Lorenz postulate means. Thats where I am getting stuck.

Comment: Please state the version of postulate 5 you are using.

Comment: If two lines are cut by a transversal so that the sum of the interior angles on one side of the transversal is less than 180, the the two line meet on the same side.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Suppose Lorenz Postulate is false in the Presence of the 5th postulate and reach a contradiction.

Suppose Lorenz Postulate is true and the 5th Postulate is false and reach a contradiction.